# I get this Error in log2(exprs(eSet)) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, runtime-error, bioconductor, limma

I work with the gene expression dataset "GSE1824", downloaded from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE1824.
To begin processing this data, I loaded the required packages on R studio:

```
# load libraries
library(affy) 
library(limma)
library(genefilter)
library(hgu133a.db) 
library(GEOquery)  
library(huex10stprobeset.db)
library(pd.huex.1.0.st.v2) 
library(Biobase)
```

I successfully loaded and unzipped the CEL files in GSE1824_RAW.tar and stored the CEL files in a directory I will call "GEMusicAR3/Cel Files".The directory only contains the following CEL files:

```
GSM31867_SKNMC.CEL
GSM31868_SiMa.CEL
GSM31869_CHP126.CEL
GSM31870_SHSY5Y.CEL
```

I set the host directory using:

```
> getwd()
 "C:/Users/xxx/Documents"

> HostDir <- getwd()
```

To process the CEL files,  I ran the following commands:

```
setwd(HostDir)  

setwd(paste0("GEMusicAR3/Cel Files",dataset,sep="")) # directory of CEL files

>abatch<-ReadAffy()

>eSet<-mas5(abatch)

background correction: mas 
PM/MM correction : mas 
expression values: mas 
background correcting...done.
22283 ids to be processed
|                    |
|####################|

> log2(exprs(eSet))
Error in log2(exprs(eSet)) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I am not able to figure out the cause of the error in:

```
Error in log2(exprs(eSet)) : 
      non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

This code has been working well without any error until recently.

On trying to discover the possible cause of the error, I have obtained the following information:

```
> eSet
ExpressionSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 22283 features, 4 samples 
  element names: exprs, se.exprs 
protocolData
  sampleNames: GSM31867_SKNMC.CEL GSM31868_SiMa.CEL GSM31869_CHP126.CEL GSM31870_SHSY5Y.CEL
  varLabels: ScanDate
  varMetadata: labelDescription
phenoData
  sampleNames: GSM31867_SKNMC.CEL GSM31868_SiMa.CEL GSM31869_CHP126.CEL GSM31870_SHSY5Y.CEL
  varLabels: sample
  varMetadata: labelDescription
featureData: none
experimentData: use 'experimentData(object)'
Annotation: hgu133a 

> exprs(eSet)
[[1]]
eSet

> class(eSet)
[1] "ExpressionSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"

> str(exprs(eSet))
List of 1
 $ : symbol eSet
```

I will be very grateful for any hint on the possible cause of the error:

```
Error in log2(exprs(eSet)) : 
      non-numeric argument to mathematical function.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you edit the post adding the output of: `dput(head(exprs(eSet)))`

Answer (score 4):

I repeated your steps, and they do work for me. I get:

```
> head(log2(exprs(eSet)))
          GSM31867_SKNMC.CEL.gz GSM31868_SiMa.CEL.gz GSM31869_CHP126.CEL.gz GSM31870_SHSY5Y.CEL.gz
1007_s_at              9.582691             9.538568               9.386841              10.030941
1053_at                9.773821             9.518747               8.653242               9.086055
117_at                 6.823635             6.178206               5.297840               5.884189
121_at                 9.921338             9.864903               9.660145               9.400098
1255_g_at              3.588186             7.268338               4.861870               8.804611
1294_at                7.232461             6.687944               6.721579               7.630187
```

You also say it used to work for you before, so this seems like a library versioning issue. Please update your question with the output of `sessionInfo()` after you load all the packages you use. Here's mine:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 28 (Workstation Edition)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=ru_RU.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] hgu133acdf_2.18.0   affy_1.58.0         Biobase_2.40.0      BiocGenerics_0.26.0 genefilter_1.62.0  
[6] limma_3.36.2       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17          AnnotationDbi_1.42.1  zlibbioc_1.26.0       splines_3.5.0        
 [5] IRanges_2.14.10       bit_1.1-14            lattice_0.20-35       xtable_1.8-2         
 [9] blob_1.1.1            tools_3.5.0           grid_3.5.0            DBI_1.0.0            
[13] yaml_2.1.19           survival_2.41-3       bit64_0.9-7           digest_0.6.15        
[17] preprocessCore_1.42.0 affyio_1.50.0         Matrix_1.2-14         S4Vectors_0.18.2     
[21] bitops_1.0-6          RCurl_1.95-4.10       memoise_1.1.0         RSQLite_2.1.1        
[25] BiocInstaller_1.30.0  compiler_3.5.0        stats4_3.5.0          XML_3.98-1.11        
[29] annotate_1.58.0
```

Or you can just try using Bioconductor release 3.7 — this is the version that works for me, and hopefully the libraries keep their interfaces within a single Bioconductor release.

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation could be that the *exprs* function in the **dplyr** package masks the *exprs* function in the **Biobase** package since both of functions have the same name in both packages.

https://support.bioconductor.org/p/109128/#109719

I have solved the problem by placing  `*exprs=Biobase::exprs*` at the top of my script.

```
# load libraries
exprs=Biobase::exprs
library(affy) 
library(limma)
library(genefilter)
library(hgu133a.db) 
library(GEOquery)  
library(huex10stprobeset.db)
library(pd.huex.1.0.st.v2) 
library(Biobase)

setwd(HostDir)  
setwd(paste0("GEMusicAR3/Cel Files",Datset,sep=""))
abatch<-ReadAffy() 
eSet<-mas5(abatch)  
SI<-log2(exprs(eSet))

> head(SI)
          GSM31867_SKNMC.CEL GSM31868_SiMa.CEL GSM31869_CHP126.CEL GSM31870_SHSY5Y.CEL
1007_s_at           9.582691          9.538568            9.386841           10.030941
1053_at             9.773821          9.518747            8.653242            9.086055
117_at              6.823635          6.178206            5.297840            5.884189
121_at              9.921338          9.864903            9.660145            9.400098
1255_g_at           3.588186          7.268338            4.861870            8.804611
1294_at             7.232461          6.687944            6.721579            7.630187
```

I admit that I have the **dplyr package** installed on my computer but I did not load it into the work space so why did it interfere? There is no **library(dplyr)** on my script.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20141514)

Comment: @arnt: this *is* an answer to his question; he describes what the problem was and how he solved it.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka Yes, I see that now. It didn't look like a complete answer before the revision, though. (Nice editing, BTW.)